# How to show ui dynmaic row saved values in edit form magento2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, dynamic-rows

I am facing an issue with dynamic rows in ui form...created a form with dynamic rows and saved successfully but in edit form the saved values of dynamic rows not displaying...how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use data provider with array index and set the values.